# Temporarily modify where the return key moves the selection

Tags: excel, vba, cell, selection

I want, when I press the return key, to move the selection one cell to the right.

I know this option can be changed under options in Excel.

I want to set this option programmatically so it only works with one workbook when it loads, but not with other workbooks.

So the option will be reset back to the original "down" action when the workbook is closed.

Answer (score 0):

While maybe not completely recommended – using TAB would be how most people work this – You can change the option with the [MoveAfterReturnDirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.moveafterreturndirection) property.

So if you would have something like

```
Private Sub Workbook_WindowActivate(ByVal Wn As Excel.Window)
    Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection = xlToRight
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_WindowDeactivate(ByVal Wn As Excel.Window)
    Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection = xlDown
End Sub
```

in the code for the workbook, that should accomplish something along the lines of what you are asking.

Notice that this will change the setting for anyone who are using the workbook, and if they had anything else than Down set, then that will change.
You could work around this by capturing the original value using a global variable, but I wouldn't bet my life on that it wouldn't mess up someones setting at some point.
**Actually, testing the latter managed to somehow set my settings to "left"**, after closing the book.

An even worse way to do it would be to completely change the function of the Enter key, using the `OnKey` method. Making the Enter key return a Tab key press. The approach would be the same, but using [OnKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.onkey) and then creating a sub that uses something like [SendKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.sendkeys) to return the Tab press.